# Create a right angled triangle using rotate transform to correct hover effect on triangle

Tags: html, css

I want to create a triangle which looks like red triangle in below image:

[image]

So, I tried my luck with css as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
<div class="div-3"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.div-1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    border-bottom: 385px solid #222;
    border-right: 175px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events:none;
}

.div-2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 45px;
    border-bottom: 285px solid #ED3237; 
    border-right: 130px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 5;    
}

.div-3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 45px;
    border-bottom: 286px solid #222;
    border-right: 105px solid transparent; 
    width: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events:none;        
}
```

**And I got it. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrmb6p7d/1/)**

Now, I want to change the triangle's color to blue when I hover over it.

So, I tried this CSS:

```
.div-2:hover{
    border-bottom: 285px solid blue; 
}
```

At first sight it looks like it is working fine. But we can notice the problem if we take a look at it closely.

Whenever mouse pointer is on transparent area of `.div-2`, then also color of triangle is changed. I don't want that. I only want to change the color of triangle to blue when cursor is hovered over visible(red) part of `.div-2`.

So, I again searched on google. Which explained me that I should use `rotate transform` instead of `borders` of div.

But I can't find a good tutorial on creating right angled triangles of different width and height as used above. So, I asked this question. Here is the question: How to create a triangle as shown in above image using rotate transform, css3 property.

**Update:**

SVG is really easy. But I want it done with css because I also intend to hide the bottom part of carousel as shown here:[image]

Comment: I think u should try SVG.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Please check the update part of question. Where I explain the reason for not using SVG. I may be wrong because I am not sure about SVG's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all due respect, your request doesn't make much sense. From where I see it, you should not be asking for *do this **using that** (or the other) **technique***.

Code is convention.
It all boils down to using some conventions over others, in order to display the result we want in particular browsers. It really does not matter what technique or language one uses, as long as they achieve the result without side-effects on other functionality/behavior.

Getting back to your question, you'll always have trouble trying to control the `:hover` state of an element while hovering a border but not the other.

You could, of course, add a mask to your element thus limiting pointer-events but, than again, why not use the mask in the first place, for display?

Here's how I'd tackle this layout:

```css
.image-container {
  background-color: #222;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path:  polygon(0 0, 73% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 27% 100%);
  clip-path:  polygon(0 0, 73% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 27% 100%);
}

l-border,
r-border {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #600;
  top: 0;
  transition: background-color .5s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .3, 1);
}

l-border:hover,
r-border:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

l-border {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 24% 100%, 27% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 24% 100%, 27% 100%);
}

r-border {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(73% 0, 100% 50%, 76% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(73% 0, 100% 50%, 76% 0);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* changing both borders when hovering image 
  just showing you it's possible */
.image-container img:hover ~ * {
  background-color: #f50;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/450" />
  <l-border></l-border>
  <r-border></r-border>
</div>
```

Depending on image ratio or even responsiveness, you might prefer `px` instead of `%`:

```css
.image-container img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 150px) 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 150px 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 150px) 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 150px 100%);
}

l-border {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 130px 100%, 150px 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 130px 100%, 150px 100%);
}

r-border {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 130px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 150px) 0);
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 130px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 150px) 0);
}
```

What I personally do is go to [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to get a basic shape polygon going fast (close to what I want) and fine-tune it to my needs in browser, applied to the live example until it fits the current bill.

---

You should note [`clip-path`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) is not fully supported, currently at `88.42%` support. One could say there is nothing "micro" or "soft" about the `clip-path` property at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and a link to clippy. After some fine tuning, I got what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I tried my best https://codepen.io/CrUsH20/pen/owWeNo

You can change stylus preprocessor in settings it'll be shown as pure CSS. You'll need to press down-arrow at middle block and select `View compiled CSS`.

Comment: Please post the code from the codepen here as well.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. But I got a more appropriate solution in another answer, so I accepted it.